# ActionController::UrlGenerationError ... missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've read the previous answers to questions about this error, but I can't seem to adapt them to my current situation.

I'm working through the i18N section of the Tuts+ [Riding Ruby on Rails](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/riding-ruby-on-rails) course (comparing my code to what's in the [course repo](https://github.com/tutsplus/riding-ruby-on-rails-course)), and for the exercise I've had to change the default locale to Portugal (pt), and change the routes so that my Issue and Projects resources are prepended by the locale (e.g. `localhost3000/pt/issues/14`), scoped under `/:locale` in my routes file.

It seems as though the ID key is being replaced by the locale hash for some reason. When I submit a new issue I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Issues#show
Showing /Users/andrekibbe/code/new_issues/app/views/issues/show.html.erb where line #19 raised:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>nil, :locale=>#<Project id: 1, name: "First project", description: "A little description", created_at: "2015-06-20 15:34:58", updated_at: "2015-06-20 15:34:58">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have the right path name?

**Extracted source (around line #19):**

```
<p><b>Project: </b>
<%= link_to @issue.project.name, @issue.project %></p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_issue_path(@issue) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', issues_path %>
```

**issues/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @issue.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @issue.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>No followers:</strong>
  <%= @issue.no_followers %>
</p>

<p><b>Project: </b>
<%= link_to @issue.project.name, @issue.project %></p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_issue_path(@issue) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', issues_path %>
```

Here are the `create` actions of the Issues and Projects controllers:

**issues_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @issue = Issue.new(issue_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @issue.save
      format.html { redirect_to @issue, notice: t('issues.created') }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @issue }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @issue.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The show method of my Issues controller, asked for by @Pavan, is the Rails default. Not much to see here.

**issues_controller.rb**

```
def show
end
```

My routes:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "/:locale" do
    get 'timeline/index'

    resources :projects
    resources :issues
  end
end
```

**rake routes**

```
timeline_index GET    /:locale/timeline/index(.:format)    timeline#index
      projects GET    /:locale/projects(.:format)          projects#index
               POST   /:locale/projects(.:format)          projects#create
   new_project GET    /:locale/projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
  edit_project GET    /:locale/projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
       project GET    /:locale/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
               PATCH  /:locale/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
               PUT    /:locale/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
               DELETE /:locale/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
        issues GET    /:locale/issues(.:format)            issues#index
               POST   /:locale/issues(.:format)            issues#create
     new_issue GET    /:locale/issues/new(.:format)        issues#new
    edit_issue GET    /:locale/issues/:id/edit(.:format)   issues#edit
         issue GET    /:locale/issues/:id(.:format)        issues#show
               PATCH  /:locale/issues/:id(.:format)        issues#update
               PUT    /:locale/issues/:id(.:format)        issues#update
               DELETE /:locale/issues/:id(.:format)        issues#destroy
```

I changed the paths to those suggested by @nathanvda, but suggestions yielded the following error message from within Rails framework code itself:

```
NoMethodError in IssuesController#index
undefined method `set_locale' for #<IssuesController:0x007fd2f9fc2460>
Extracted source (around line #432):

case filter
    when Symbol
      lambda { |target, _, &blk| target.send filter, &blk }
    when String
      l = eval "lambda { |value| #{filter} }"
      lambda { |target, value| target.instance_exec(value, &l) }
```

Comment: Please update your post with `show` method of your `issues_controller`

Comment: @Pavan Added, but as I mentioned in the edit, it's only the default method, empty except for what it inherits.

Comment: Try giving it like this `<%= link_to @issue.project.name, @issue.project.id %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you scoped everything under the locale, rails route helpers are assuming the first helper is the locale.

If you write your link as follows you should be good:

```
link_to @issue.project.name, [I18n.locale, @issue.project]
```

But this seems a bit tedious. Even better is the tip from the[I18n guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params): add the locale to the default url options, add the following method to your `ApplicationController`:

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
  { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
end
```

and then your links should be working as they were.

Comment: In both cases, I'm running into a `NoMethodError in IssuesController#index` message directly from Rails. I'll add the full message to the main post when I get a chance, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This answer is correct. `default_url_options` solves the issue.

Comment: So I answered the question, but because you have another problem popping up, it is not good enough? I have to foresee all possible problems you would encounter? The error means you call a method `set_locale` (probably in a `before_filter`? which is not defined). This should be another question, you can't keep extending questions.

Comment: @nathanvda The fact that it was a NoMethodError led me to believe it was the same problem, not "another" problem (though I realize now that it's a different method being reported). The show method never appeared in the stack trace prior to the new NoMethodError. I've accepted your answer and appreciate the help. I'm sure answer is correct, but making it work is something I need to figure out on my own.

Comment: @nathanvda OK, it worked. Had to read the i18n guides for a enough context to understand why I couldn't get it to work initially, but you had the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Same case with me. the old code was

```
<%= link_to "Click Here to reset your password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.password_reset_token), target: :_blank %>
```

I fix it with this update

```
<%= link_to "Click Here to reset your password", edit_password_reset_url(I18n.locale, @user.password_reset_token), target: :_blank %>
```

Thanks @nathanvda